# Constrain allowed Mime Types in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, api, mime-types

I'm trying to build an API with Spring boot. That API has an endpoint that is going to accept some images as MultiPartFile. The problem that I'm facing is constraining the mime type of files that are being uploaded. I don't want to have a util method to do it but rather a configuration. I was trying the below code but it is not working because I'm able to upload a pdf where I should only be able to upload a png mime type.

```
@Component
public class MimeTypeConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        MimeMappings mimeMappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mimeMappings.add("png", "image/png");
        factory.setMimeMappings(mimeMappings);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use a filter here ?

Comment: What do you mean by use a filter?